# What is a number sequence rule?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Let's say that we have a sequence of odd numbers $1, 3, 5, 7 ...$. From this sequence we build a spiral in the spirit of the [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral).

Can you write down a rule for numbers change in the diagonal $3, 15, 23, 43, 59, 87, 111, 147, ...$?

Source. [Math Olympiad 2020](https://www.formulo.org/ru/olymp/2020-math-ru/)

Comment: I think it's too straightforward to be considered as a puzzle.

Comment: Do you know the answer?

Comment: Your description of odd numbers combined with the spiral essentially gives away everything - [rot13](https://rot13.com/)(gur vagreiny vf sbhe gvzrf 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... jvgu cnvef fjnccrq). The actual olympiad would require you to rigorously prove it, but it's not the case here (unless the results are counter-intuitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is asking how to generate the numbers of that diagonal, starting from 3 it could be something like this:

> The generic number $n$ in the sequence can generate the subsequent using:
>  $$n+2s$$
>  Where $s$ is the number of positions that separate the two numbers, following the spiral in numerical ascending order.